# Using ProgressDialog in ActionBar (Android)

Tags: android, android-actionbar, progressdialog

I am trying to move a ProgressDialog to my ActionBar.

I know how to put it in the action bar and animate it (I think), like this:

In progress.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1" >

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progress"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ProgressBar>

</LinearLayout>
```

in menu.xml

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/Refresh"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_refresh"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="Refresh"/>
```

in my activity

```
    case R.id.Refresh:
        item.setActionView(R.layout.progress);
        return true;
```

Here is my current PD (in the activity) in `onPreExecute` and `onPostExecute` of my AsyncTask:

```
// Pre  
dialog = new MyProgressDialog(---.this);
dialog.show(---.this);


// Post    
dialog.dismiss(---.this);
```

So how do I move this so that the action bar indicator is activated in `onPreExecute` and then stopped in `onPostExecute`?

EDIT:  I am not only looking for a refresh, but a "loading" indicator when you first load an activity (or do something that requires the PD to activate).  It should be hidden by default.

Comment: After the edits, the title no longer matches the question, I think.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Guess I will have to answer my own question.  This was very simple actually.

in Activity, just above `setContentView`

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
```

`AsyncTask`

```
// pre
setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);

// Get Data

// post
setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);
```

Answer (score 4):

if you have to require in  **onCreate()**

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);  
setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);
```

or if you are using the **support package** it would be

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);  
setSupportProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);
```

if you finding any trouble then make comment.